# how to solve this error we are facing version error init and all pakages not supported ho to solve it

Tags: flutter

The current Dart SDK version is 2.14.4.

```
Because test_core >=0.3.17 depends on glob ^2.0.0 and build_test 0.10.12+1 depends on test_core >=0.2.4 <0.4.0, build_test 0.10.12+1 requires glob ^2.0.0 or test_core >=0.2.4 <0.3.17.
```

(1) So, because build_test >=0.10.3+1 <1.3.7 depends on glob ^1.1.0 and build_test >=0.10.7 <=0.10.12 depends on test_core ^0.2.4, build_test >=0.10.7 <=0.10.12+1 requires test_core >=0.2.4 <0.3.17.

```
Because no versions of build_test match >0.10.12+1 <0.11.0 and build_test >=0.1.1 <=0.10.3 requires SDK version >=1.8.0 <2.0.0 or >=2.0.0-dev.32 <2.0.0, build_test >=0.1.1 <0.10.3+1 or >0.10.12+1 <0.11.0 is forbidden.
And because build_test >=0.10.3+1 <0.10.10 depends on stream_transform ^0.0.11, build_test >=0.1.1 <0.10.10-∞ or >0.10.12+1 <0.11.0 requires stream_transform ^0.0.11.
And because build_test >=0.10.7 <=0.10.12+1 requires test_core >=0.2.4 <0.3.17 (1), build_test >=0.1.1 <0.11.0 requires test_core >=0.2.4 <0.3.17 or stream_transform ^0.0.11.
And because google_maps_flutter_platform_interface >=1.0.1 <2.0.0-nullsafety depends on stream_transform ^1.2.0, if build_test >=0.1.1 <0.11.0 and google_maps_flutter_platform_interface >=1.0.1 <2.0.0-nullsafety then test_core >=0.2.4 <0.3.17.
Because google_maps_flutter >=0.5.30 <1.1.0 depends on google_maps_flutter_platform_interface ^1.0.4 and google_maps_flutter >=0.5.27 <0.5.30 depends on google_maps_flutter_platform_interface ^1.0.1, google_maps_flutter >=0.5.27 <1.1.0 requires google_maps_flutter_platform_interface ^1.0.1.
```

(2) Thus, if build_test >=0.1.1 <0.11.0 and google_maps_flutter >=0.5.27 <1.1.0 then test_core >=0.2.4 <0.3.17.

```
Because test_core >=0.3.12-nullsafety <0.3.12-nullsafety.8 requires SDK version >=2.10.0-0 <2.12.0 and test_core >=0.3.12-nullsafety.8 <0.3.12-nullsafety.16 depends on stream_channel >=2.1.0-nullsafety <2.1.0, test_core >=0.3.12-nullsafety <0.3.12-nullsafety.16 requires stream_channel >=2.1.0-nullsafety <2.1.0.
And because test_core >=0.3.12-nullsafety.16 <0.3.12-nullsafety.17 depends on test_api 0.2.19-nullsafety.7, test_core >=0.3.12-nullsafety <0.3.12-nullsafety.17 requires stream_channel >=2.1.0-nullsafety <2.1.0 or test_api 0.2.19-nullsafety.7.
And because test_core >=0.2.2 <0.2.14 depends on matcher >=0.12.5 <0.12.6 and test_core >=0.2.14 <0.3.8 depends on matcher >=0.12.6 <0.12.7, test_core >=0.2.2 <0.3.8-∞ or >=0.3.12-nullsafety <0.3.12-nullsafety.17 requires stream_channel >=2.1.0-nullsafety <2.1.0 or test_api 0.2.19-nullsafety.7 or matcher >=0.12.5 <0.12.6 or >=0.12.6 <0.12.7.
And because test_core >=0.3.8 <0.3.11 depends on test_api 0.2.17 and test_core >=0.3.11 <=0.3.11+1 depends on test_api 0.2.18, test_core >=0.2.2 <0.3.11+2 or >=0.3.12-nullsafety <0.3.12-nullsafety.17 requires stream_channel >=2.1.0-nullsafety <2.1.0 or test_api 0.2.17 or 0.2.18 or 0.2.19-nullsafety.7 or matcher >=0.12.5 <0.12.6 or >=0.12.6 <0.12.7.
And because test_core >=0.3.11+2 <0.3.12-nullsafety depends on test_api 0.2.18+1 and test_core >=0.3.12-nullsafety.17 <0.3.17 depends on test_api 0.2.19, test_core >=0.2.2 <0.3.17 requires stream_channel >=2.1.0-nullsafety <2.1.0 or test_api 0.2.17 or 0.2.18 or 0.2.18+1 or 0.2.19-nullsafety.7 or 0.2.19 or matcher >=0.12.5 <0.12.6 or >=0.12.6 <0.12.7.
And because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on both matcher 0.12.10 and stream_channel 2.1.0, if test_core >=0.2.2 <0.3.17 and flutter_test any from sdk then test_api 0.2.17 or 0.2.18 or 0.2.18+1 or 0.2.19-nullsafety.7 or 0.2.19.
And because if build_test >=0.1.1 <0.11.0 and google_maps_flutter >=0.5.27 <1.1.0 then test_core >=0.2.4 <0.3.17 (2), if build_test >=0.1.1 <0.11.0 and google_maps_flutter >=0.5.27 <1.1.0 and flutter_test any from sdk then test_api 0.2.17 or 0.2.18 or 0.2.18+1 or 0.2.19-nullsafety.7 or 0.2.19.
And because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on test_api 0.4.2 and barber_app depends on google_maps_flutter ^0.5.27+3, build_test >=0.1.1 <0.11.0 is incompatible with flutter_test from sdk.
So, because barber_app depends on both flutter_test any from sdk and build_test ^0.10.3, version solving failed.
```

pub get failed (1;     So, because barber_app depends on both flutter_test any from sdk and build_test ^0.10.3, version solving failed.)